# Minimize a cost function?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a cost function and its gradient calculated with finite element discretization (values at integrations points)  and I have the data in a text file.
The problem is the cost function and its gradient not mathematically explicit, calculated numerically at some points xi in volume V at each increment of time t using the finite element method. The results for the function and its gradient are stored in a text file.
How to minimize this function? any idea?

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent ?

Comment: If it's that simple, I'm not asking here. It seems like you have read only the title. Thank you

Comment: Do you want [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) or other way/formula for the interpolation?

Comment: You ask for help, but don't offer much details apart from the title. What kind of answer do you expect? What's your problem? Please put some effort into your question.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is the cost function and its gradient not mathematically explicit, calculated numerically at some points xi in volume V at each increment of time t using the finite element method. The results for the function and its gradient are stored in a text file.

Comment: Read the data. Find the minimum values. For every minimum value, check if the gradient isn't pointing towards a smaller element(meaning that there is a smaller element that you didn't catch due to the discretization). Profit. Not sure if there is much else to be done. We don't have your data, we don't have a reproducible example. If the function is behaving "nicely" some kind of polynomial approximation might be possible - fit a curve so that both the points and the gradients fit, find the minimum. Hope for the best.

Comment: Thank you so much @shamis for your response, I used panda-Python to read the data and I transfer them to an array format. the problem is how to handle the cost function and its gradient to give them as input for an optimization algorithm? Thanks, Best Wishes

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can do what you’re thinking to do. If your finite element simulations are already done then the only thing you can do is to create a proxy model of your results as a function of your parameters. One possibility is to model your results by interpolating them (using for example SciPy griddata https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) and use that as your proxy model.

Then you select your favorite optimization algorithm, specify your parameters (that have to be part of the griddata interpolant) and you’re ready to go. Depending on how many finite element simulations you have done you can expect very bad/meaningless outcomes (if you have too few) or very good ones (if your finite element simulations cover almost the entire optimization space).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help so much, It's sound like a great idea I'll try it ,thanks again Best wishes

Comment: Thanks, @infinity77 can you please help with how to minimize an interpolated function ? like in the example you mentionned [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) ,

Comment: Show us some of your efforts, with code: where you got to, where you got stuck and why. Unfortunately I’m not going to do the exercise for you.

Comment: Thanks @inifinity77 I try it but the problem is the griddata returned an array of interpolated values and I try to put it as the input of the algorithm but it returned "numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"